# How can I dynamically load Perl modules and use their functions?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to switch some `use` statements in my code to `require` for modules I only use if certain conditions are met (e.g. the program might be loaded 1,000 times between times those modules are needed), in order to lower the overhead and improve the execution speed of my program (I've been using Devel::NYTProf to profile my code and some modules were adding significant execution time even when I didn't use them in a certain session).

I've run into an issue where the script dies on load because symbols aren't defined (that won't be defined until that module is imported). Is there a way to tell Perl that the symbols will be imported at runtime? A simple example: I only want to use Data::Dumper if I call a routine that triggers it:

```
sub dataDumper {
    require Data::Dumper;
    Data::Dumper->import;
    say STDERR Dumper @_;
}
```

However, calling `Dumper` on that third line causes an exception. I can work around that by referring to `Data::Dumper->Dump` instead. However, a similar issue with LWP::UserAgent proves a bit sticker because LWP::UserAgent imports HTTP::Request. I haven't come up with a variation of `my $request = new HTTP::Request GET => $params->{'url'};` that avoids throwing an exception.

Assuming I can that to work, is there any reason why this approach is a bad idea? Am I losing any sort of optimizations by not loading these modules at compile time? On a module like LWP, it seems like an easy call -- I just don't use it much. I'm a bit more confused on whether to try to dynamically switch between (for example) Text::Textile and Text::MultiMarkdown (I usually only need one per execution.

Comment: If startup time is so onerous, it might be worth looking into a persistent service (like FCGI is to CGI).

Comment: @ikegami That sounds intriguing. Is there a good guide you could recommend to taking an existing program and implementing it with a persistent system? It sounds like PSGI is the best route for that today?

Comment: Sorry, no. . . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fully qualified names and don't import anything.

```perl
sub dataDumper {
    require Data::Dumper;
    say STDERR Data::Dumper::Dumper(@_);
}
```

> However, a similar issue with LWP::UserAgent proves a bit sticker because LWP::UserAgent imports HTTP::Request.

The terminology in this statement is wrong. LWP::UserAgent doesn't import anything. In fact, it has no `import` method at all. It *loads* HTTP::Request, by `use`ing it. So perl will switch to compile time at the point LWP::UA is `require`d, compile it, and load HTTP::Request, HTTP::Response and HTTP::Date (and a few others), [all explicitly without importing anything](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl/source/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#L8) into LWP::UserAgent's namespace either.

> ```
> $request = new HTTP::Request GET => $params->{'url'};
> ```

I can't reproduce this blowing up if HTTP::Request hasn't been loaded. If it doesn't get executed, it won't error.

```perl
if (0) {
    HTTP::Request->new(GET => '/foo');
    new HTTP::Request GET => '/foo';
}
```

This is fine. You should of course use the first form, and not the indirect object notation, because it's ambiguous, but it makes no difference.

If you were to use [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common), which imports `GET` and `POST` et al to quickly generate HTTP::Requests, you can also just `require` it at runtime, and then use the fully qualified name.

```perl
if ($make_web_request) {
  require LWP::UserAgent;
  require HTTP::Request::Common;

  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  $ua->request(HTTP::Request::Common::GET('https://example.org'));
}
```

> Am I losing any sort of optimizations by not loading these modules at compile time?

No. If your code is started a lot of times, and goes lots of different paths, then loading things only if you need them is totally fine to do. It makes very little real difference. Perl switches between compile time and run time for every single `require` anyway. Generally that's not a penalty at all.

Comment: Re "*Use fully qualified names and don't import anything.*", That's not what made the difference; it was the addition of the parens.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you! This seemed to solve my issue -- thanks for the tips on HTTP::Request!

Answer (score 5):

In sub calls, parens around arguments can only be omitted for declared subs.

```perl
say STDERR Dumper(@_);
```

Note that prototypes on subs you load this way will be ignored.

---

There is no problem with the second line as it doesn't involve a sub call. Method calls aren't affected.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   if ($ARGV[0]) {
      require LWP::UserAgent;   # or HTTP::Request
      my $request = new HTTP::Request GET => "https://stackoverflow.com";
   }

   say "ok";
' 0
ok

$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   if ($ARGV[0]) {
      require LWP::UserAgent;   # or HTTP::Request
      my $request = new HTTP::Request GET => "https://stackoverflow.com";
   }

   say "ok";
' 1
ok
```

As such, class modules are particularly useful here. Consider a plugin model in complicated cases.

---

> *Am I losing any sort of optimizations by not loading these modules at compile time?*

Constants need to be replaced slower function calls which can't be folded.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -M5.010 -e'
   use constant FOO => 2;
   say 2 + FOO;
'
...
2  <;> nextstate(main 188 -e:3) v:{,fea=1
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[IV 4] s/FOLD
5  <@> say vK
...
```

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -M5.010 -e'
   say 2 + FOO();
   require constant; import constant FOO => 2;
'
...
2  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:2) v:{,fea=1
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[IV 2] s
5  <0> pushmark s
6  <#> gv[*FOO] s/EARLYCV
7  <1> entersub[t2] sKS/TARG
8  <2> add[t3] sK/2
9  <@> say vK
...
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question by what do you mean by "class modules" vs. "plugin models" here? I have Perl modules that implement classes that I've essentially been using as plugins for different functionality. Is there a better way to approach that?

Comment: Class module... A module that provides a class (as opposed to subs)

Comment: Plugins are dynamically loaded modules expected to implement an interface.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar, but like this. Somehow the `state` makes this a lot faster even though `require` won't load it a second time:

```
sub something {
    state $rc = require Foo;
    ...
    }
```

If I want to import things

```
sub something {
    state $rc = do { require Foo; Foo->import };
    ...
    }
```

Remember what `use` actually is:

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo;
    Foo->import(...);
    }
```

The `BEGIN` merely does that at compile time. If you do all the same steps later, you end up in the same place (just later).

Comment: Thank you! Once again you come to the rescue on my code. Very grateful! I didn't know about "state." It seems like a good thing to integrate into my code. I've already shaved 30% off load times trying this.